# What does find(x==1) in MATLAB exactly return and what is equivalent to it in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matlab, find

I'm trying to do what the following MATLAB code does in python but I can't quite understand the output of it. This is the MATLAB code

```
A = zeros((48,60));

A(3,5) = 1;
A(3,6) = 1;
A(48,60) = 1;
A(47,60) = 1;
A(24,30) = 1;
A(38,45) = 1;

f = find(A == 1);
```

The last line with `f` returns `[195;243;1416;2150;2879;2880]` which is a column of numbers. But I don't get how these numbers are obtained from find(). It seems like it isn't multiplying the row and column numbers. Why am I getting those numbers? Also, what should I do to get the same thing in python?

```
A= np.zeros(48, 60)
A[2, 4] = 1
A[2, 5] = 1
A[47, 59] = 1
A[46, 59] = 1
A[23, 29] = 1
A[37, 44] = 1

np.where(A ==1)
```

I've tried `np.where(A== 1)` but it only returns indices of the rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find command in matlab returns the linear indices of each element. More can be find here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#budquyz-1.

The equivalent python code would then be `np.argwhere` which also returns the indices: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html

To get the exact same behavior as matlab, you have to transform the matrix into a vector:

```
A= np.zeros((48, 60))
A[2, 4] = 1
A[2, 5] = 1
A[47, 59] = 1
A[46, 59] = 1
A[23, 29] = 1
A[37, 44] = 1

np.argwhere(np.ravel(A)==1)
```

Comment: I've actually tried `np.argwhere(A==1)` as well, but it just returned
(array([ 2,  2, 23, 37, 46, 47], dtype=int64),
 array([ 4,  5, 29, 44, 59, 59], dtype=int64))
Is there a way to get the same linear indices like MATLAB?